# Buying a new rear wheel

Tags: wheels

My rear wheel is very bent and I need a new replacement, but I'm not sure on which wheel I'm supposed to get for my bike I was told I could get a freewheel but I don't know what that means. I assumed it was like getting a new front wheel

This is the information I believe may be relevant that I know about my bike, it has:

- Shimano Cassette CS-HG41 7 Speed 11-28T
- Shimano BB-UN26 68 X 122.5mm - Shimano BBUN26
  68 X 122.5mm
- SHIMANO CHAINSET 48/38/28 170 M171
  [image]

I believe the rim size is 700 x 38c - 28 but I'm not too sure so I have attached an image of the tyre below

[image]

Comment: From the photos the chainring looks very good - so there's minimal wear on the bike.  What is the problem with the rear wheel, such that it needs replacing ?

Comment: Look on the rim itself for a sticker that gives the rim dimensions.  (Only a 50/50 chance there will be one, but it's worth a shot.)  Look on the rear hub itself for the manufacturer's part number.  (This should be there, if you look closely enough.)

Comment: @Criggie The bike wheel is very wobbly, spokes are broken and the wheel appears to be bent so when I ride, it rubs against the brake pads and frame. Went to the bike shop thinking it needed truing and was told to get a new bike wheel.

Comment: @Syk OK your photo shows a rim with eyelets on the spokes, which is generally a good thing.  The broken spokes will cause most of the wobble.  If it were mine, I'd fit replacement spokes where needed, and then have a go at truing it.  Once its true enough, ride for a day and then check it again.  A bike shop could sink a lot of time into truing a wheel that is beyond saving, and then has to charge you for it, so its in their interest to sell a new complete wheel.  Give it a go, worst that happens is you're out the cost of the spokes, and your time, but you've learned a useful process.

Comment: @Criggie That's true, thanks. I'll buy some spokes and try and truing it today

Comment: @Criggie Wanted to give an update, got some new spokes and replaced them and then I trued the wheel and it's working brilliant. Thanks for the suggestion to replace the spokes. I'm going to try ride it tomorrow to work, if any spokes break then I'm going to replace the wheel but hopefully not.

Comment: @Criggie Tried riding the bike, and it went awesome, no broken spokes. Thanks you saved me from wasting my money

Comment: @Syk good work - not only have you learned a skill to apply again in the future, you've saved some cash, acquired some tools, and reduced consumerism and throw-away society by a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"700 x 38c - 28 "  You have a "700c" sized road tyre, in width of 38mm and the rim is 28 mm wide.  This tyre size is also known as 622-38 because it is 622 mm across.

A freewheel and freehub are the two different parts that do the same job.  Your bike might have either, but not both.  This is how the cogs in the middle of the rear wheel attach to the wheel's hub.

If you replace the rear wheel completely, you can reuse the tube and tyre.  You will need new rim (28mm wide) and rimtape.  New spokes, and a new hub.  If the cassette and chain are unworn you can transfer them over.
Your cassette is a "shimano branded CS-HG41 with 7 speeds" so its not the old-style freewheel

> For other readers, if the current hub were a freewheel (screws off) then replace it with a cassette that slides onto the hub and is held on with a lockring.  This will mean a new chain.  Freehubs are technically superior to Freewheels.

Your bike has 7 speeds in the rear, so either stick with that or if you want more gears then you'll also have to change the right-side shifter as well.  Don't feel compelled to upgrade the number of gears.